# How can I get language in TextView?

Tags: android, string, textview

I have a question. I want to detect what language in Textview so that I can set its max length. For example:

English --> length: 16

Korean  --> length: 14

Comment: if you are detecting it through length then check textview length...

Comment: Use http://www.lextek.com/langid/li/

Comment: @NiravRanpara how can I use it with Android Studio?

Comment: Use api... does not matter Eclipse or Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

This will tell you current language selected , then you can set textsize according to language in code.